# Creating an integral to represent the volume of the intersection of two balls in cartesian coordinates

Tags: multivariable-calculus, multiple-integral

The question states:

Let $A$ be the intersection of the balls

$x^2+y^2+z^2\leq 9$ and $x^2+y^2+(z-8)^2\leq 49$

I am asked to just set up the iterated triple integral that represents the volume of $A$ in cartesian coordinates.

What I am able to determine so far is that for the equation

$x^2+y^2+z^2\leq 9 $:

$-\sqrt{9-x^2-y^2}\leq z \leq \sqrt{9-x^2-y^2}$

$-\sqrt{9-x^2}\leq y \leq \sqrt{9-x^2}$

$-3\leq x \leq 3$

If I were to set up this integral it would be:

$\int_{-3}^{3}\int_{-\sqrt{9-x^2}}^{\sqrt{9-x^2}} \int_{-\sqrt{9-x^2-y^2}}^{\sqrt{9-x^2-y^2}} dzdydx$

But I don't know how I'm supposed to set up the intersection of the two balls?

I was thinking of setting the two equations equal to each other so that

$x^2+y^2\leq 9-z^2$ and

$x^2+y^2\leq 49-(z-8)^2$

so then I have $9-z^2=49-(z-8)^2$

Solving for $z$ I get $z=3/2$ but I don't know what to do with this information.

Comment: It is simpler to integrate with respect to the $z$ variable first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{align}
V &= \int_{8-7}^{\frac32}\left(\int\int_{x^2+y^2 \le 49-(z-8)^2}\mathrm dx\mathrm dy\right)\mathrm dz + \int_{\frac32}^{3}\left(\int\int_{x^2+y^2 \le 9-z^2}\mathrm dx\mathrm dy\right)\mathrm dz\\
&=\int_{1}^{\frac32}\int_{-\sqrt{49-(z-8)^2}}^{\sqrt{49-(z-8)^2}}\int_{-\sqrt{49-(z-8)^2-y^2}}^{\sqrt{49-(z-8)^2-y^2}}\mathrm dx\mathrm dy\mathrm dz + \int_{\frac32}^{3}\int_{-\sqrt{9-z^2}}^{\sqrt{9-z^2}}\int_{\sqrt{9-z^2-y^2}}^{\sqrt{9-z^2-y^2}}\mathrm dx\mathrm dy\mathrm dz.
\end{align}

The idea is similar to what you mentioned when you wanted to compute each ball separately. The first term is the part of the intersection that is clipped by the second ball and the second term is the part clipped by the first ball.

Comment: Oh gosh, thanks so much for your answer! Just wondering where you got your bounds from though? Especially the 8-7 and 3/2? would you mind just explaining that a little? Also since it needs to be iterated doesn’t that mean I need bounds for x y and z?

Comment: The $\frac32$ is the solution of the equation $9 - z^2 = 49 - (z-8)^2$ which give you the $z$ coordinate of the intersection points of the two spheres in any plan going through the $z-$axis. For the bounds on $x$ and $y$, I gave you the bounds on $x^2 + y^2$ and I will edit the answer to add the bounds on $x$ and $y$ separately.

Comment: wow I totally understand now, thanks so much again for your help! I was going crazy I accepted your answer and it says the bounty can be awarded in the next 20 hours

Comment: Hi, I just want to double check something. If I were to write this as a single integral, would the answer be: 
$\int_{\frac{-3\sqrt{3}}{2}}^{\frac{3\sqrt{3}}{2}}\int_{-\sqrt{27/4-x^2}}^{\sqrt{27/4-x^2}}\int_{-\sqrt{49-x^2-y^2}+8}^{\sqrt{9-x^2-y^2}}$

Answer (score 1):

$\def\bbr{\mathbf{R}}$It is simpler to exploit the symmetries. From the picture below, you can see clearly that the intersection is a [normal domain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_integral#Normal_domains_on_R3) in $\bbr^3$, which means that you can write it as
$$
A=\{(x,y,z)\mid (x,y)\in D, f(x,y)\le z\le g(x,y)\}
$$
where $D$ is some two-dimensional region on the $xy$-plane. You can then set up the volume as
$$
V=\iint_D\int_{f(x,y)}^{g(x,y)}1\;dz dA
$$
and reduce it further to an iterated integral by working on the region $D$.

---

The ball $x^2+y^2+z^2\le 9$ can be written as:
$$
E_1=\{(x,y,z)\mid (x,y)\in D_1,-\sqrt{9-x^2-y^2}\le z\le\sqrt{9-x^2-y^2}\}
$$
where $D_1=\{(x,y)\mid x^2+y^2\le 9\}$ is a 2D region.

Similarly, the ball $x^2+y^2+(z-8)^2\le 49$ can be written as
$$
E_2=\{(x,y,z)\mid (x,y)\in D_2,8-\sqrt{49-x^2-y^2}\le z\le 8+\sqrt{49-x^2-y^2}\}
$$
where $D_2=\{(x,y)\mid x^2+y^2\le 49\}$. So
$$
E_1\cap E_2=\{(x,y,z)\mid (x,y)\in D, 8-\sqrt{49-x^2-y^2}\le z\le\sqrt{9-x^2-y^2} \}\tag{1}
$$
for $D=\{x^2+y^2\le R^2\}$ with some real number $R$. To find out $R$, observe that the intersection curve (see picture below) of the two spheres is given by the equations:
$$
\begin{cases}
x^2+y^2+z^2= 9 \\
x^2+y^2+(z-8)^2= 49
\end{cases}
$$
which is equivalent to
$$
\begin{cases}
x^2+y^2+z^2= 9 \\
9-z^2+(z-8)^2= 49
\end{cases}
$$
which is
$$
\begin{cases}
x^2+y^2+z^2= 9 \\
z=\frac{3}{2}
\end{cases}
$$
So $R = \frac{3\sqrt{3}}{2}$. Now you can write the volume as
$$
V=\iint_D\int_{8-\sqrt{49-x^2-y^2}}^{\sqrt{9-x^2-y^2}}1\cdot dz dA
=\int_{-R}^{R}\int_{-\sqrt{R^2-y^2}}^{\sqrt{R^2-y^2}}\int_{8-\sqrt{49-x^2-y^2}}^{\sqrt{9-x^2-y^2}}1\cdot dzdxdy
$$
[image]