# Are these two triple integrals the same?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I need to write an iterated triple integral to represent the volume of the intersection of two balls in cartesian coordinates.

The two balls are $x^2+y^2+z^2\leq 9$ and $x^2+y^2+(z-8)^2 \leq 49$

I realize the question is asking to write an iterated triple integral, so I think that means just one integral.

I already got the answer from another [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3081698/creating-an-integral-to-represent-the-volume-of-the-intersection-of-two-balls-in) that I asked.

However I want to know if that answer, i.e. :

$$\int_{1}^{3/2} \int_{-\sqrt{49-(z-8)^2}}^{\sqrt{49-(z-8)^2}}\int_{-\sqrt{49-(z-8)^2-y^2}}^{\sqrt{49-(z-8)^2-y^2}}dxdydx+ \int_{3/2}^{3}\int_{-\sqrt{9-z^2}}^{\sqrt{9-z^2}}\int_{-\sqrt{9-z^2-y^2}}^\sqrt{9-z^2-y^2}dxdydz$$

Is equivalent to if I were going to use just one single triple integral in cartesian coordinates

$$\int_{\frac{-3\sqrt{3}}{2}}^{\frac{3\sqrt{3}}{2}}\int_{-\sqrt{27/4-x^2}}^{\sqrt{27/4-x^2}}\int_{-\sqrt{49-x^2-y^2}}^{\sqrt{9-x^2-y^2}}dzdydx$$

EDIT: The way I get it as one single integral would be like this:

$(z-8)^2-z^2=40\implies z=\frac{3}{2}$

$\implies x^2+y^2=9-(\frac{3}{2})^2=\frac{27}{4}$

So $-\frac{27}{4}\leq x\leq \frac{27}{4}$

$-\sqrt{\frac{27}{4}-x^2}\leq y \leq \sqrt{\frac{27}{4}-x^2}$

and we enter the surface z through $-\sqrt{49-x^2-y^2}+8$ and exit through $\sqrt{9-x^2-y^2}$

Comment: You miss the number $8$ in the bound for integral with respect to $z$.